# highlight.js doesn't highlight on markup load from JavaScript event

Tags: asciidoctor, highlightjs

When I put a code manually in html, highlight.js work perfectly

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asciidoc.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pygments.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="highlightjs-theme.css">
</head>
<body>
    <pre><code>
        using System;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Display the number of command line arguments.
            Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
        }   
    </code></pre>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
But when I use asciidoctor.js to convert markup to html highlighter doesn't work on the generated html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asciidoc.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pygments.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="highlightjs-theme.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- static c# code-->
    <pre><code class="csharp">
        using System;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Display the number of command line arguments.
            Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
        }   
    </code></pre>

    <textarea col=20 rows=3 id="raw_code" onkeyup="preview()"></textarea>
    <!-- Dynamic c#-->
    <div id="target"></div>
    
    <script src="asciidoctor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
        function preview(){
            var content = document.getElementById('raw_code').value
            var asciidoctor =  Asciidoctor();
            const html = asciidoctor.convert(content,{doctype: 'article' ,safe: 'safe',header_footer: false,  attributes: { 'source-highlighter': 'highlightjs' }})
            document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = html;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result after the above code
[image]
We can see that the code insert on key press doesnot highlight but the code insert manually when the page was load is highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad()` comes before the Asciidoc markup is converted to HTML, so the HTML isn't in the DOM when `hljs` does its work.

Also, it looks like you'll want to include a call to `hljs` in the `preview()` function so that the syntax highlighting isn't lost on each keypress in the `raw_code` textarea:

```js
        function preview(){
            var content = document.getElementById('raw_code').value
            var asciidoctor =  Asciidoctor();
            const html = asciidoctor.convert(content, {
                doctype: 'article',
                safe: 'safe',
                header_footer: false,
                attributes: {
                    'source-highlighter': 'highlightjs'
                }
            })
            var target = document.getElementById('target')
            target.innerHTML = html
            hljs.highlightBlock(target)
        }
```

Comment: `hljs.highlightBlock(target)` is highlight the whole target rather than `code` tag content

Comment: simple solution to this can be like this: `var blocks = document.querySelectorAll('pre code:not(hljs)');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(blocks, hljs.highlightBlock);`

Comment: If the target will only contain just the Asciidoctor-generated HTML, it's safe to highlight the target.